# calculating error rate of a system comming up with percentage answers

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, classification

I would appreciate ideas in this regard. 
Imagine I have a software (constraint satisfaction solving) which solves a problem and comes up with the answers like this:

100 % A is the solution,

100 % B is the solution,

70 % C is the solution,

50 % D is the solution,

while the correct answer is C.

Imagine that ultimately all the answers will be considered in my system so coming up with the correct answer though with less certainty is still an achievement. I will not discard the answers with less percentage than 100. However, it is important to find a proper evaluation function or error rate calculation.

How can I calculate the error rate of my system.

One may say the above example has 100 % error rate as the answer is not either A or B. What if the correct answer is B and only B. what will be the error rate?

Comment: you error rate is 100% since the system say with 100% certainty that the answer is A while the correct answer is C

Comment: imagine that the system is supposed to be dynamic so that through time it can get more information and change its answers. I guess it can't have 100 % error rate as it did actually come up with the correct answer having 70 % rate. I mean all the answers are indeed being considered, Or imagine that the correct answer is B, and it has given B as the answer as well as A which is not the answer. So how to calculate the error. I believe the problem is how to add the dynamic method of calculating the error rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious way is to compute the average error for all replies.

Either using Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD):

```
(|1-0| + |1-0| + |.7-1| + |.5-0|) / 4 = (1+1+.3+.5)/4 = 2.8/4 = 0.7
```

Or Mean Square Error (MSE):

```
(|1-0|^2 + |1-0|^2 + |.7-1|^2 + |.5-0|^2) / 4 = (1+1+.09+.25)/4 = 2.34/4 = 0.585
```

Both have their pros and cons.

(Above example is using a "correct" vector of `0 0 1 0`, but it would also allow the answer to be e.g. "any of A B C D" by using `1 1 1 1`, for example. It is up to you to ensure that these values e.g. sum up to 1 or not). Similarly, you might want to normalize your algorithm output to sum up to 1, if you know that exactly one answer is correct. In your example, this would normalize the answer to `.3125 .3125 .21875 .15625`, which probably has a lower error.)